# If statement in UNIX for loop not excluding the variables I want excluded

Tags: bash, unix, join

Here is the UNIX code I wrote to join all sea ice extent files into one file. I tried to do this by joining the first two years then creating a for loop that then excludes those first two years so they do not get added twice. They are still being added twice.

#!/bin/bash

```
#this creates the file output_extent initially but then the if statement in the following loop does not work and there are two columns for 1979 and 1989
join polar_ice_extent_data.1979.txt polar_ice_extent_data.1980.txt > output_extent.txt

#for loop with an if statment to join all files that include extent except the first two into a new file.
#Have to create a temporary file because it will not append back onto output_extent directly
for file in *extent*.txt; do
    if [ $file != polar_ice_extent_data.1979.txt ] && [ $file != polar_ice_extent_data.1980.txt ]; then
        join output_extent.txt $file > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt output_extent.txt;
    fi
done
```

**File example:** This is repeated for 1979-2015

```
#year   1979
jan 15.6
feb 16.38
mar 16.52
apr 15.56
may 14.08
jun 12.65
jul 10.52
aug 8.18
sep 7.22
oct 9.42
nov 11.18
dec 13.57
```

Comment: Without seeing the file contents, its tough to wager on what's going wrong here.

Comment: Please add also what should be the sample output? Is it all files you need to concatenate? please be more specific in your questions.

Answer (score -1):

It needed single quotation marks around my file names in the if statement.

Comment: Single quotes make no difference for the filename `polar_ice_extent_data.1980.txt` in your script as posted. Is there more to it?

Comment: Perhaps you have filenames with spaces?

Comment: All I changed were putting single quotation marks around the polar_ice_extent_data.1979.txt and polar_ice_extent_data.1980.txt in the if statement and it worked. I removed them again and then it did not exclude them. Not sure why it worked but it did.